# Pine Script seconds resolution timeframe.period

Tags: pine-script

What is the value for timeframe.period in seconds ?

the only possible way for me to detect seconds resolution is by using
timeframe.isseconds

1 minute would be

```
if timeframe.period == "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is "S" for 1sec, "5S", "15S" or "30S".

You can use PineCoders' [`f_resInMinutes()`](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-convert-the-current-resolution-in-a-numeric-format) function to return the TF in float minute format. Makes things simpler.

You can run a simple discovery test using:

```
//@version=4
study("")
f_print(_text) => var _label = label.new(bar_index, na, _text, xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, color(na), label.style_none, color.gray, size.large, text.align_left), label.set_xy(_label, bar_index, highest(10)[1]), label.set_text(_label, _text)
f_print(timeframe.period)

// ————— Converts current chart timeframe into a float minutes value.
f_resInMinutes() => 
    _resInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60             :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.                  :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 60. * 24            :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)
plot(f_resInMinutes())
```

> **Disclosure**: the link in this answer points to a PineCoders FAQ entry.
> I am a member of the PineCoders community and I most probably wrote that FAQ entry. PineCoders is a TradingView-supported group of volunteer Pine coders and PineCoders' website is strictly educational. Neither TradingView nor PineCoders benefits financially from sending traffic to pinecoders.com, and the site contains no affiliate/referral links.

Comment: awesome answers

Answer (score 0):

I use the following - which gets the ms between two bars and divides for seconds

```
int(time[0] - time[1])/1000
```